# Hive - Manual Conversion of Date from UTC to CSRT

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

The oracle database stores a date offset column which is used to convert the UTC dates to CST. Then when you SELECT you would do this:

```
    select ConnectedDatetimeUTC,
CAST(connecteddatetimeutc + (startdtoffset/ (24 * 60 * 60)) as timestamp(3)) as connecteddattimeManual2
from table1
```

We are struggling to get this implemented in HIVE SQL.

Comment: Please add a small data sample including required results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with    table1 as 
        (
            select  timestamp '2017-02-28 23:58:41' as connecteddatetimeutc
                   ,1234                            as startdtoffset
        )

select  ConnectedDatetimeUTC
       ,startdtoffset
       ,from_unixtime (unix_timestamp(connecteddatetimeutc) + startdtoffset) as connecteddattimeManual2

from    table1
;
```

---

```
+----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| connecteddatetimeutc | startdtoffset | connecteddattimemanual2 |
+----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-02-28 23:58:41  |          1234 | 2017-03-01 00:19:15     |
+----------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Roger that sir!  The only tweak I needed was a CAST to INT on the offset because it was defined as a DECIMAL.